# Getting a list of tag value from xml file

Tags: xml, dom, xml-parsing, php

i'd like to get the values of a tag in `xml` in `array` by `php`.
I have used this snippet:

```
$images = parseXmlFileForTagName("Rambod_catalog.xml", "Thumbnail");
$prices = parseXmlFileForTagName("Rambod_catalog.xml", "Retail_Price");

echo $images[0], "          ", $prices[0];

/**
 * @param string $xmlFile
 * @param string $tagName
 *
 * @throws InvalidArgumentException
 * @return DOMNodeList
 */
function parseXmlFileForTagName($xmlFile, $tagName)
{
    $doc = new DomDocument;
    $r = $doc->load($xmlFile);
    if (!$r) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Failed to load file %s', $xmlFile));
    }

    return $doc->getElementsByTagName($tagName);
}
```

but an error appears:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array in /path/to/index.php on line 400

Why is the cause of this error? How can i modify my code to fix it?

Comment: You are accessing a DOMNodeList like an array which is not possible, it uses a different notation to access the list's values. How is documented in the php manual: http://php.net/domdocument.getelementsbytagname - you need to modify your code accordingly to fix it, but it's really too localized for an answer IMHO.

Comment: Also please do not duplicate your own questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037936/converting-xml-to-array-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you've got is that you make use of a `DOMNodeList` as if it were an array. However that specific type can not be used with `ArrayAccess`:

```
echo $images[0], "          ", $prices[0];
```

This is why you see the error. You might want to convert the `DOMNodeList` to an array first, which can be done with the `iterator_to_array` using on a `DOMNodeList` which has been previously outlined in the related question *[Implements DOMDocument to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15579195/367456)*.

```
/**
 * @param string $xmlFile

...

 * @return DOMElement[]
 */
function parseXmlFileForTagName($xmlFile, $tagName)
{

...

    $elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName($tagName);

    return iterator_to_array($elements, FALSE);
}
```

Now the function returns an array of `DOMElement` nodes, zero-indexed. However those elements do not automatically convert to string in string context:

```
echo $images[0], "          ", $prices[0];
```

So that you need to read their `nodeValue` (as I guess you are looking for that value):

```
echo $images[0]->nodeValue, "          ", $prices[0]->nodeValue;
```

And that should do it. However as I also commented on your other (possible duplciate) question, if you use simplexml instead of DOMDocument, this might be more easy as it has magic access to node values so you can directly echo a result. Also You can just access one or multiple tags by writing their name. No need for such a function actually.